# GCP Artifacts NPM repository doesn't seem to support searching

Tags: unity-game-engine, npm, google-cloud-platform, google-artifact-registry

I've got a simple NPM repository setup through GCP Artifacts and I've linked it to Unity as a custom scoped registry. I'm able to install new packages and see updates come through but I don't seem to be able to see all my available packages rather than having to install them all manually.

If I call https://europe-west1-npm.pkg.dev/PROJECT_NAME/REPOSITORY_NAME/v1/search?text=BASE_SCOPE with the right authentication credentials it just returns that it can't find anything

```
{
    "error": "Requested entity was not found."
}
```

/v1/all also returns the same even though that should list all the packages according to the [NPM Registry API](https://github.com/npm/registry/blob/master/docs/REGISTRY-API.md#get-all)

I've also started a [thread](https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-to-make-custom-packages-from-gcp-artifactory-show-up-to-browse-them.1447564/) over at the Unity Forums as I thought this was an issue in the Unity Package Manager but it appears that GCP's NPM repository doesn't seem to behave, how can I get it to allow for searching so I can see my non-installed packages?

Comment: Have you checked with the Documentation [Listing files](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/nodejs/manage-packages#file)

Comment: I did yeah, the `gcloud` commands work and are able to list all the packages but it's the NPM api that doesn't want to cooperate here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Google's documentation](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/nodejs/manage-packages) it seems that you can only get a list of packages through the gcloud cli and it doesn't provide support for the NPM api. Thus this seems to currently not be possible